# Como verificar se um campo do tipo text ou ntext é null ou vazio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como posso verificar se um campo do tipo **ntext** é null ou vazio no `where`?

Tenho o seguinte `select`

```
SELECT  Subject, Notes from DocumentNotes
where Notes is null or Notes = ' '
```

mas ao compara ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 402, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 3
>       Os tipos de dados ntext e varchar são incompatíveis no operador equal to.

*Exemplo:*

```
declare @textos table
(
  Subject  int,
  Notes ntext
)

insert into @textos values
(1, ' '),
(2, ''),
(3, 'teste')
```

**Quero apenas o Subject <> 3**

***Obs: Uso o Sql Server 2008.***

Comment: Gostaria de sabe o porque do -1, para que possar melhorar a pergunta,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar `datalength(Notes)=0` ou `Notes like ''`.

```
SELECT  Subject, Notes from DocumentNotes
where Notes is null or Notes like ' '

Ou 

SELECT  Subject, Notes from DocumentNotes
where Notes is null or datalength(Notes)=0
```

Answer (score 4):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
SELECT  Subject, Notes from DocumentNotes
where Notes is null or datalength(Notes)=0
```

**Referencia:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-text-column-is-empty

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

Com `COALESCE` você consegue uma solução mais elegante:

```
SELECT  Subject, Notes 
FROM DocumentNotes
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar, COALESCE(Notes, '')) = ''
```

No caso do SQL Server, o mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT  Subject, Notes
FROM DocumentNotes
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar, ISNULL(Notes, '')) = ''
```

Ou seja, se o valor for `NULL` ele será convertido em `''`, então basta comparar com `''`. A conversão para `nvarchar` resolve o erro de incompatibilidade de tipo com operador que você estava obtendo.

Comment: as duas soluções retornam Mensagem 402, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 13
Os tipos de dados ntext e varchar são incompatíveis no operador equal to.

Comment: Editado, faltava uma conversão.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0e9e/4

Answer (score 3):

Para testar as soluções propostas, foi criada a seguinte tabela:

```
  use tempDB;
  CREATE TABLE DocumentNotes (Subject varchar(50), Notes ntext);

  INSERT into DocumentNotes 
    values (1, space(1)), (2, N''), (3, N'teste 3'), 
           (4, N'   teste 4'), (5, NULL), (6, space(10)),
           (7, replicate(cast(N' ' as nvarchar(max)), 10000) + N'teste 7');
  go
```

No caso 4 inicia com espaços mas há conteúdo na coluna. O caso 7 possui 10 mil espaços antes do texto 'teste 7'. O código estará correto se retornar somente as linhas 1, 2, 5 e 6, pois as linhas 3, 4 e 7 contêm texto.

Ao criar o código, é necessário ficar atento às peculiaridades de colunas do tipo ntext, cuja capacidade de armazenamento é de até (2^30 - 1).

A função Ltrim() pode ser utilizada para eliminar espaços à esquerda. Se somente houver espaços, o resultado é space(0) ou ''.  Mas a função Ltrim() não aceita colunas ntext como parâmetro; então, basta converter previamente para nvarchar(max).

A sugestão de código é:

```
  SELECT  Subject, Notes 
    from DocumentNotes
    where Ltrim(Cast(IsNull(Notes, space(0)) as nvarchar(max))) = space(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma versão diferente de uma forma já apresentada aqui.

Neste caso, converte-se somente o Notes e depois compara.

```
select * from tmp_textos
where isnull(convert(varchar,Notes),'')=''
```

Comment: Não é igual a forma apresentada pelo bfavaretto?

Comment: Não é igual, é parecida. Perceba que ele converte por fora.