# Como fazer uma query no sql que retorne os dados de uma tabela quando o dado for vazio?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Bom, eu criei uma tabela chamada parcelas, que quando o cliente paga ela é inserido 'PAGO' na coluna situacao, e quando não estar pago ele permanece em branco. Eu queria buscar as informações dessa coluna para saber quando a conta não foi paga, dessa forma trazer somente os clientes que possuem a coluna situacao vazio.

Exemplo:

```
select * from parcela where situacao =''
```

Porém não traz os dados da tabela situacao e quando eu coloco:

```
select * from parcela where situacao ='PAGO'
```

Ele traz os dados perfeitamente

Comment: resolvi com isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99229/como-verificar-se-um-campo-do-tipo-text-ou-ntext-%C3%A9-null-ou-vazio

Comment: Você pode responder sua própria pergunta, assim ela não fica sendo visitada com o assunto já resolvido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuidado! Existe uma grande confusão quando se diz que um determinado valor está "vazio".

O termo "vazio" pode estar se referindo a coisas diferentes:

1. conteúdo nulo [`NULL`];
2. conteúdo em branco [`length(s) == 0`];
3. conteúdo com apenas espaços em branco [`length(s) != 0` e `length(trim(s)) == 0`].

Para você ser capaz de identificar um campo em qualquer uma das situaçoes acima citadas, seria necessario a construção do seguinte filtro:

```
SELECT * FROM parcela WHERE (length(trim(situacao)) == 0) OR (situacao IS NULL);
```

Ou:

```
SELECT * FROM parcela WHERE (trim(situacao) == '') OR (situacao IS NULL);
```

Ou ainda: (*conforme mencionado no comentário do @CleberGriff*)

```
SELECT * FROM parcela WHERE length(trim(ifnull(situacao, ''))) = 0;
```

Ou então, especificamente no cenário exposto na sua pergunta:

```
SELECT * FROM parcela WHERE (situacao != 'PAGO') OR (situacao IS NULL);
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5f6c/2)

Comment: Vale também utilizar IFNULL para definir um padrão quando o valor for nulo:

``SELECT * FROM parcela WHERE (TRIM(IFNULL(situacao, '')) = '')``